# Как писать комментарии от имени канала в pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

В общем, есть бот, который должен комментировать посты от имени канала. Пока что он просто комментит от имени человека.

```
from pyrogram import filters, Client, types
import random

api_id = 333333
api_hash = '33333333'
ADMIN_GROUP = -767881209
choices = ['', '', '']
app = Client('anon', api_id, api_hash)
GROUPS = [-1001826063681]

@app.on_message(filters=[filters.channel, filters.group])
async def wait_messages(client: Client, message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.id in GROUPS:
        m = await app.get_discussion_message(message.chat.id, message.id)
        await app.set_send_as_chat(message.chat.id, -1001690557176)
        await m.reply(random.choice(choices))


app.run()
```

Comment: https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/set_send_as_chat первая ссылка в гугле

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, Выдало вот эту шляпу:
pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.BadRequest: Telegram says: [400 Bad Request] - [400 SEND_AS_PEER_INVALID] (caused by "messages.SaveDefaultSendAs")

Comment: А что вы сделали? это вообще другая ошибка

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, await app.set_send_as_chat(message.chat.id, -1001690557176).
Даже переставлял аргументы, но никак не помогло

Comment: Так у вас ошибка вызвана не этой командой, судя по ошибке, которую вы прикрепили

Comment: Вот что было перед этим (Полностью не уместил ошибку)

 File "s.py", line 26, in wait_messages
    await app.set_send_as_chat(-1001690557176, message.chat.id)
  File "set_send_as_chat.py", line 52, in set_send_as_chat
    return await self.invoke(

Comment: весь код покажите, обновите вопрос

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, обновил

Comment: Ваш аккаунт может отправлять сообщения как `-1001690557176` этот канал?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Так-то должен. Телеграм премиум есть и аккаунт является админом канала. Даже админом в канале назначил, но всё равно никак

Comment: Так вы зайдите с клиента и посмотрите, возможно ли это. И покажите вывод `await app.set_send_as_chat(message.chat.id, -1001690557176)`

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, извиняюсь за долгий ответ. Да, доступ есть. У меня как-то один раз получилось, но теперь опять никак не хочет отправлять сообщение. Я подумал, что надо брать не группу, где посты выходят, а чат с обсуждениями (это переменная m в коде), но прикол в том, что и это не помогло. Уже какой день подряд голову ломаю и, возможно, щас что-то сломаю уже из вещей. Помогите

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно передавать id чата а не канала, первым аргументом set_send_as_chat, message.chat.id - это id канала.
Вот так нужно исправить:

`await app.set_send_as_chat('id ЧАТА с комментариями','id, от чьего имени отправляем')`

Чтобы его получить простым способом - перешлите сообщение ОТ ИМЕНИ ГРУППЫ, где собираются коментарии боту @getmyid_bot
Сейчас самому понадобилось сделать подобное, пришлось разобраться.

Так же нужно будет изменить строчку `if message.chat.id in GROUPS:`
Если у вас в GROUPS список чатов - то message.chat.id там не будет.